# With Docker based AWS ElasticBeanstalk Applications, does 'Restart App Server(s)' on the environment ALWAYS pull down a new docker image

Tags: docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've set up a Multi image Docker Application in Amazon's ElasticBeanstalk (EB).  When  I deploy an environment, it pulls down a specific docker image from the repo (docker hub).

The question is:
When you select "Restart App Servers" in EB for a given environment, does their  agent *ALWAYS* pull a fresh copy of the image down from your repo?

The use case is: let's say the deployed image in the environment is tagged 'latest'. I want be confident if any changes happen and the 'latest' image gets updated, by simply "Restart App Servers" in the environment it will get the changes--not use the locally stored 'latest' image.

Answer (score 0):

With Platform version "64bit Amazon Linux 2016.03 v2.1.1 running Multi-container Docker 1.9.1 (Generic)", the latest version of the image is always pulled from the repository when the "Restart App Server" operation is requested. I didn't find any AWS documentation though.

-Janne